# How Read XML file?

Tags: java, xml

I have file XML file,I want read this file but I want use loop "FOR" for read element.
Not :I use "org.w3c.dom"
*file XML :*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<Labels>
 <xLabel>
  <NamexLabel>wer</NamexLabel>
  <NamexLabel>we</NamexLabel>
  <NamexLabel>sdf</NamexLabel>
 </xLabel>
 <yLabel>
  <NameyLabel>1sa</NameyLabel>
  <NameyLabel>2as</NameyLabel>
  <NameyLabel>3as</NameyLabel>
 </yLabel>
</Labels>
```

I need read this file but I can't access by loop to all element in "yLabel"  and "xLabel".

*code java :*

```
File xmlfile = new File("D:\\Project//createFile.xml");
DocumentBuilderFactory documentFactory =DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = documentBuilder.parse(xmlfile);
doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("xLabel");
    for (int temp = 0; temp < nodeList.getLength(); temp++) {
        Node node = nodeList.item(temp);
        if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                      Element student = (Element) node;
                      System.out.println(" Name : " +     student.getElementsByTagName("NamexLabel").item(0).getTextContent());

                }
            }
 nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("yLabel");
    for (int temp = 0; temp < nodeList.getLength(); temp++) {
            Node node = nodeList.item(temp);
            Element student = (Element) node;
*******//I change get Elemets to loop For****
            System.out.println(" Name : " + student.getElementsByTagName("NameyLabel").item(0).getTextContent());
                        System.out.println(" Name : " + student.getElementsByTagName("NameyLabel").item(1).getTextContent());
            System.out.println(" Name : " + student.getElementsByTagName("NameyLabel").item(2).getTextContent());

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Comment: try the javax.xml package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("xLabel");
for (int temp = 0; temp < nodeList.getLength(); temp++) {
    Node node = nodeList.item(temp);
    NodeList namexLabelNodes = node.getChildNodes();

    for (int i = 0; i < namexLabelNodes.getLength(); i++) {
        System.out.println(" Name : " + namexLabelNodes.item(i).getTextContent());
    }
}
```

For yLabel will be same code.

Comment: Do not mention it. Good luck!